# Java Swing LaF doesnt apply the theme to executable Jar app

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

im trying to use a custom theme im my java app, when i run it in netbeans, the themes apply like so,

[with theme applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAa8U.png)

however, when i build and compiled the app and run the executable jar file, this is what i get

[executable jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h62yh.png)

i tried to modify the main function to recognize and use the custom theme

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        IntelliJTheme.setup(LoginPage.class.getResourceAsStream("/carbon.theme.json"));
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

i want to apply the theme at the executable file to make it presentable

Comment: [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#:~:text=%22Look%22%20refers%20to%20the%20appearance,and%20a%20corresponding%20ComponentUI%20subclass.)

Comment: How is the new theme created and packaged to be usable in any Java program? Maybe usability of the theme program away from the IDE (externally) is a factor.

Comment: i've added  the LaF jar to the project folder and its lib in the dist folder and i still get the same results